# Is it mandatory or just a convention for a function to return an iostream while one of its arguments is also iostream

Tags: c++

Recently I was reading Accelerated C++ and found this interesting code from exercise answers.　Here is the full code,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "4_4.h"

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;
using std::streamsize;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <exception>
using std::domain_error;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;

vector<double> square_double(const unsigned int range) 
{
  vector<double> squares;
  if (range > squares.max_size())
    throw domain_error("Range argument exceeds vector limit.");

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < range; i++)
    squares.push_back(i * i);

  return squares;
}

double GetNumberOfDigits(const double i)
{
  return i > 0 ? log10(i) + 1 : 1;
}

ostream& print_squares(ostream& os, const vector<double>& v)
{
  if (os)
  {
    streamsize digits_i = (streamsize) GetNumberOfDigits(v.size());
    streamsize digits_v = (streamsize) GetNumberOfDigits(v.back());

    for (vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) 
    {
      streamsize s_size = os.width();
      os << setw(digits_i) << i << " " << setw(digits_v) << v[i] << endl;
      os.width(s_size);
    }
  }

  return os;
}

int ex4_4()
{
  vector<double> v = square_double(500);
  print_squares(cout, v);

  return 0;
}
```

The purpose of this function is to calculate squares of values between a range with a fixed step size. What confuses me is the answer only used the `print_square` function **once**, the `for` loop inside this function has done all the work for printing, so why he uses `ostream&`? There is no **chained-ostream** output residing in this code block right?

The code itself is easy to understand but the return `ostream&` of this function confused me. Why should I use `ostream&` rather than just `void` ? Anyways, `cout` is just using its "side-effect" to print things out, So why bother return itself? Is it some sort of convention, because i saw no further following output using `cout` after this codeblock.

Appreciated!

Comment: Edited, please check, thanks!

Comment: Better. With this context, I would guess it's the author's habit to return the stream, rather than a convention or a requirement. The author might not have even noticed that `void` could be less confusing. But that's a guess, not a good answer. Remy Lebeau gave a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only kind of function that is *required* to return its input `ostream` is an `operator<<` implementation.  Other kinds of functions are not *required* to do this, or even *encouraged* to.

It *might* make sense to have `print_squares()` return its `ostream` if it were used as part of a related `operator<<` implementation, eg:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const vector<double>& v)
{
    return print_squares(os, v);
}
```

But, even without a return value, `print_squares()` could still be used:

```cpp
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const vector<double>& v)
{
    print_squares(os, v);
    return os;
}
```

But either way, this is not the case in the *specific example* you have quoted.  The return value of `print_squares()` is completely ignored by the caller, so what the return value is declared as is irrelevant.  But, if `print_squares()` were to be used in other code projects, perhaps its return value might not be so irrelevant.

Whether `print_squares()` (or any other function) needs to return its input `ostream` or not really depends on how the calling code wants to use that return value.  There is no fixed convention here.

Comment: chaining is a common habbit when it comes to iostream programming.  eg. ‘print_square(std::cout<<"[[",vec)<<"]]\n";‘

Comment: *"[..] that is **required** to return its input `ostream` is an `operator<<`"*. It is just a good habit/style, it is not required by the language. It would *just* break user expectation.